# Regex in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm ultimately trying to use the following regex expression.

```
SELECT  *
into table
FROM    table2
Where
(Description ~ '\bD\s*(&|AND|&AMP;|N|AMP|\*|\+)\s*B.*')
```

However this returns the following errors:

*[XX000] ERROR: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occured while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'P;|N|AMP|*>>>HERE>>>|+)s*B.*'. Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occured while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'P;|N|AMP|*>>>HERE>>>|+)s*B.*'. code: 8 ...*

Any idea on the fix?

Comment: Try using the correct word boundary pattern, `'\yD\s*(AND|&AMP;|N|AMP|[*+&])\s*B.*'` (note `(&|\*|\+)` can be put as `[&*+]`). Everything else seems OK.

Comment: See http://rextester.com/YGKLG42407

Comment: Are you sure you do not have `E'...pattern...'`?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `\b` with `\y` (or `\m`) to fix the pattern, and you may put single chars inside a capturing group into a character class where you do not have to escape them, `(&|\*|\+)` -> `[*+&]`. Note you do not need `.*` at the end, unless you are *matching* (if you just check for a regex match with `~` you do not need it);

Use

```
'\yD\s*(AND|&AMP;|N|AMP|[*+&])\s*B'
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/KDU20987):

```
CREATE TABLE tb1
    (website character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tb1
    (website)
VALUES
    ('D AND B...'),
    ('ROCK''N''ROLL'),
    ('www.google.com'),
    ('More text here'),
    ('D N Brother')
;

SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE website ~ '\yD\s*(AND|&AMP;|N|AMP|[*+&])\s*B';
```

Output

[image]